# Use concat with as inside concat funcation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, concatenation, alias

I have three columns in my table: firstName, lastName and jobTitle.
I want to concat firstName and lastName as Fullname then concat Fullname and jobTitle.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You would do:

```
select concat_ws(' ', firstName, lastName) as Name,
       concat_ws(' ', firstName, lastName, jobTitle) as NameTitle
```

You cannot re-use a column alias in the same `select`, so you have to repeat the expression.

EDIT:

If you want one column of that form, then perhaps:

```
select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname, ', ', jobtitle)
```

Comment: Actually, I want to print out just 1 column conforming the form (Fullname, jobtitle) but your have 2 column Name and NameTitle

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use a column alias for this, you'd have to simply select all three of the columns at once.

```
CONCAT(firstName, lastName, jobTItle) as nameJob
```

Comment: Please explain why, I just want to concatenate firstName and lastName as fullName to show just 1 column CONCAT(fullName, " ", jobTitle).
Why can't I do that?

Comment: Because the concat function expects either a string or a column name. For some reason it doesn't support aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like that

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname,CONCAT(fullname,'-',jobTitle) as info
FROM yourTable
```

another example

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname,CONCAT(fullname,'-',jobTitle) as info
FROM yourTable WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) = "Bob Marley"
```

Comment: MySql displays the error "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'fullname' in 'field list'", Could you suggest another answer.

Comment: Yes I can, shoud be about your version. Look this example http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-concat-in-mysql.aspx